# After scrolling my RecycleView Cards are filling one screen each

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView with a Card as a adapter.

RecyvleView in MainActivity:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recvyleview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

List item Layout with the Card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem:

When I start the app I see all the elements:
[image]

But when I start scrolling every card starts filling one screen:
[image]

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List item parent layout height and cardview height change to wrap_content instead of match_parent. Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```